# easystroke broken - how to fix or which alternate software to use

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux, manjaro

I use easystroke some years now. But today it's gone :(

In the CLI I got this message:

> easystroke: error while loading shared libraries:
> libboost_serialization.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory

It seems easystroke is not under maintenance for some years now (ohh shocking!!!).
So how can I fix this or anybody knows another nice Applikation on Linux for Mouse-Gestures?

**uname -a :**

> Linux 5.4.85-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 21 21:38:53 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It looks like a dependency issue. Some options. 1. Rebuild the package with new dependencies 2. Install the old version of that package etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't see any point where I could change the libboost dependency in the build-package file (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/easystroke/#news)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to install it.
Even if the easystroke-git from AUR not work, it work to do it manually like described at the Page: https://github.com/berkeleybross/easy-gesture/blob/master/docs/build-instructions.md#releases

```
wget http://openartisthq.org/easystroke/patched-easystroke-master.tar.bz2
tar xvjf patched-easystroke-master.tar.bz2
cd patched-easystroke-master/easystroke
make
```

Comment: Now that's how ArchLinux Et al. users solve their issue \o/

Comment: At least the results count ;). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> easystroke: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.81.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Depending upon the version , download the specific libboost libs from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/

Extract the 1.81.zip file (your version), run ./bootstrap.sh and a b2 file will be generated then run ./b2, just takes a few mins to on an average system to compile. The compiled files will be located on /stage/lib (shown in the b2 output)

then run on bash
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="lib/" ./easystroke show`

this lib/ should be replaced with the absolute path, Or just copy that lib/ from /stage to somewhere and run this command.